# Meaning of "route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth0:1"

Tags: linux, networking, route, iproute

if the format is:

```
route add -host 192.168.1.20 gw 10.1.1.20 dev eth0:1
```

I know, It will route 192.168.1.20 to 10.1.1.20

Then, what's the "dev eth0:1" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inclusion of 'dev eth0:1' forces the kernel to use the eth0:1 interface for traffic matching the route specification.

Also in this case, the interface specification is for an alias interface or label configured on eth0.

Comment: Then, which ip to route to? the question format doesn't inlucde a target IP.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by target IP. The example you gave will route packets addressed to 192.168.1.20 via 10.1.1.20.

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign an interface to direct the traffic.

your interface is dev (device) eth0:1 the :1 is a logic id for the interface, cause you can configure multiple networks in an interface.

Comment: use of "dev" is optional in both `route` and its successor `ip`. If not included, the kernel will determine the most appropriate device based on existing routes and device configurations.